Pypdf merged pdfs wrong page atributes
When using pypdf merge function i get pdf file with invisible content. I found out taht coordinates of pages atributes mediBox and cropBox has some errors. Look like this:
      /MediaBox [ 0 0 595 842 0 0 595 842 0 0 595 842 ]
      /CropBox [ 0 0 595 842 0 0 595 842 0 0 595 842 ]
Let's say i'm merging two pdf documents with two and three pages. In the result pdf document will be 5 pages with different mediabox and cropbox for every page: first two pages will have mediabox and cropbox sizes merged two times and last three pages size will be merged three time for the number of pages. if i dont correct size of one of the elements this page will be displayed incorrect.
Im using pypdf 5.1.0 version
Here are my code:
    import pypdf
    def merge_pdfs(pdf_list, output_path):
    pdf_merger = pypdf.PdfWriter()
    for pdf in pdf_list:
        pdf_merger.append(pdf)
    pdf_merger.write(output_path)
    pdf_merger.close()

Here how it needs to look:
     /MediaBox [ 0 0 ### ### ]
      /CropBox [ 0 0 ### ### ]
For now im fixing it manually but its not perfect solution and i still dont know why it's happenning.
for page in range(len(merged_pdf.pages)):
    merged_pdf.pages[page].pagedata.mediabox.lower_left = (0, 0)
    merged_pdf.pages[page].pagedata.mediabox.upper_right = (595, 842)
    merged_pdf.pages[page].pagedata.cropbox.lower_left = (0, 0)
    merged_pdf.pages[page].pagedata.cropbox.upper_right = (595, 842)


After additional tests i think that the problem occures only with specific pdf files that are provided to me. Seems that my original files have some errors in atributes.

It willl help to show your source file dimensions but if they are wrong then it is your code needs to change the output to desire. For a crop box to be needed it must be smaller than media box otherwise all your output needs is only the mediabox as pypdf suggests in example. but if you do need to use a cropbox in your output then consider save and re run a seperate cropping pass using one line wrapped in a loop of pages the command for cropping includes the normal [0 0 ### ###] as ((##,##,##,##)) see https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/cropping-and-transforming.html
